# counting the number of vertices in a subtree

Tags: c++, database, algorithm

I wrote an AVL tree, I'm sure that it works correctly, but my vertex counting does not work for the subtree. Help find a mistake.

I am sure that the error is in this part of the delete function, if this is not enough, I will write its full part.
If I’m fundamentally wrong, then tell me how to implement the algorithm for finding the number of vertices in a subtree for an AVL tree

```
class Node
{
public:
    int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    int height;
    int kol; // number of vertices in the subtree
};

Node* newNode(int key){
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->key = key;
    node->left = nullptr;
    node->right = nullptr;
    node->height = 1;
    node->kol = 1;
    return node;
}
Node* minValueNode(Node* node){
    Node* current = node;

    while (current->left != nullptr)
        current = current->left;
    return  current;
}

Node* deleteNode(Node* root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    if ( key < root->key ){
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);
        root->kol--;
    }
    else if( key > root->key ){
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);
        root->kol--;
    }
    else
    {
        if( (root->left == NULL) ||
            (root->right == NULL) )
        {
            Node *temp = root->left ?
                         root->left :
                         root->right;
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                int t = root->kol;
                *root = *temp;
                root->kol = t - 1;
            }

            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            Node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);
            root->key = temp->key;
            //root->kol = temp->kol;

            root->right = deleteNode(root->right,
                                     temp->key);
        }
    }

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    return root;
}
```

Comment: `free(temp);` -- Why are you using `free` in a C++ program?  Your program has undefined behavior, since `Node` was allocated with `new`, not `malloc`.

Comment: Fair remark). I will fix it.

Comment: It's been well over 20 years since I last worked with AVL trees but if I recall correctly, only the height of the largest subtree is required for managing rotations.  If you're storing the total number of nodes too (for efficiency reasons maybe?), then you'll also need to correctly update them when rotating the tree.

Comment: The most productive use of your time is not to get someone to interpret your code.  Instead, why not create a member function that displays all the private data for a node and its subtree.  Then you call this any time you've finished doing an add, delete or rotate operation.  You'll find your error soon enough.

Comment: Please be more detailed than "does not work". That is vague enough to include your computer spontaneously shutting down (because it refuses to do more work). Furthermore, how are we to spot a problem counting nodes when that code is not shown? Please work on a [mre] to demonstrate the problem, then provide us with actual and expected output for it. (Think small -- if the problem is in deletion, then it might be enough to add a node to an empty tree, delete that node, then show the count.)